# Are low degree I/O relations in AES possible?

Tags: aes, algebraic-attack

If I restrict the degree of each monomial to say 4 or 5 at maximum. Is it then actually possible to write down the I/O relations for an AES S-box?

Comment: What do you mean by I/O relations?

Comment: Suppose x1.... X8 are input bits for the S-Box and y1....y8 are the output bits.. I'm talking about f(x1.., x8) ---> (y1....., y8) ... In these equations none of the monomials involved should be more than degree 4 or 5...